# Object Reference Error -To Uncheck Optimize Code option

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception

We were getting lots of unhandled null reference exceptions in our application as below.

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at

To get the exact line numbers in the error logs we deployed PDB files in the production environment with PDB only option enabled in release mode.

Now we are getting the line numbers error description but the lines numbers are always pointing to finally block where this is no possibility for the error to occur.

In the Project properties when give the build in release mode the Optimize code will be checked, we found that due to this option the line numbers are incorrect.

Now we are planning to give a deployment in production with this option unchecked so that we will get the correct line numbers. Wanted to check if this will have any impact to the performance of the application if we deploy with this option unchecked to production environment.

Please let me know incase if you have tried this or has come across such scenarios.

Comment: The line numbers might be off by a few, have you looked around that statement? Also, are you sure you are using the same version of the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it certainly may have impact on performance, that's what the option is there for.

Basically, you have two options:

1. Check optimize. This way, your code will be easier to debug, but it may be less efficient.
2. Don't check optimize. This way, your code will be most likely more efficient, but also harder to debug.

The difference is because if you turn optimize on, the compiler will perform more optimizations, which may transform your code so that line numbers are not accurate, you can't get the value of local variables, etc.